# How to stub a thread using Rspec?

Tags: multithreading, testing, rspec, controller, stub

I am trying to test a thread. Assume that customer, venue, message are all in the above code, but it would be very long to post. I am trying to test the "message" variable, but since it is not an instance variable and it is within a thread I am not able to test it very easily. I am assuming that stubbing the thread would be the correct route to test this with rspec, but if you have any other suggestions on how to accurately test the "message" variable that would be very helpful. Here is a basic version of what I am doing:

> ```
> Class Messages
>   def order_now
>     conf = venue.confirmation_message
>     message = "Hi #{customer.first_name}, "
>     if conf && conf.present?
>       message << conf
>     else
>       message << "your order has been received and will be ready shortly."
>     end
>
>     Thread.new do
>       ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
>         Conversation.start(customer, venue, message, {:from_system => true})
>       end
>       ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.clear_stale_cached_connections!
>     end         
>   end
> end
> ```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to get a little clever here:

```
it "should test the conversation message" do
  Conversation.should_receive(:start).with(
    instance_of(Customer), 
    instance_of(Venue),
    "your order has been received and will be ready shortly.",
    {:from_system => true}
  ).and_call_original

  message_instance.order_now.join
end
```

Basically, you can test that you call your `Conversation::start` with the right parameters. However, there's a subtlety here - you call `message_instance.order_now.join`, because `order_now` returns the thread, and you want to wait for the thread to finish running before your rspec example finishes. `#join` will block execution of the main thread until the referenced thread finishes running. Otherwise, it would be possible for the rspec example to finish running before the thread executes, resulting in a test failure.

Comment: I added more detail to the method that hopefully sheds more light on the test. I am simply trying to test that if venue.confirmation is blank that the "your order has been received and will be ready shortly." String would be shoveled into the message string. 

I would like to test the message variable, but rspec only allows you to test instantiated variables like @message, so the only way I can test the response is within the thread. Let me know what you think and how you would test the message variable with Rspec. Thanks!

Comment: You could also do something like this: `allow(Thread).to receive(:new).and_yield`